# parallel hint not working for view in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

while migrate project code from oracle 12c to 19c we are facing parallels hint issue for view.
when we are using below code the parallel degree working fine

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ 1 FROM View;
```

But , when we are give view column name explicitly in the select statement the parallel hint not working

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ id,name FROM View
```

it working fine oracle 12c but not working in oracle 19c. How to resolve this issue?

--- Pipe row function call

`SELECT * FROM TABLE(PACKAGE1.P_FILE(CURSOR(SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ C1,C2 FROM VIEW1 WHERE 1=1),'Filename.txt','directroy')) nt;`

-- Function declaration

```
FUNCTION P_FILE
            (
             P_SOURCE    IN SYS_REFCURSOR,
             p_filename  IN VARCHAR2,
             p_directory IN VARCHAR2
            )
            RETURN v_return_pipe
            PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
            PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_source BY ANY)AS
```

PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

Comment: Selecting only the literal `1` means Oracle doesn't care about actual data other than how many rows to return. So any join that can't change the row count (outer joins on a PK, for example) can be bypassed, among other optimizations. When you change this to a real column name now suddenly Oracle has to care about the value and that may require doing joins or other operations it otherwise wouldn't need to. On the parallelism-not-working question, @ibre5041's answer is good enough. You'd need to tune the view code itself and you haven't shared that with us. You also haven't shown the entire plan

Comment: @PaulW thanks for the your input. we have not done any code change but the view working fine in 12c not working 19c. i updated the view code & full explain plan. please check and provide your inputs

Comment: Thank you for the view code and fuller plan. See my answer below. So, does this query perform unacceptably for you? Is it slower than it was before?

Comment: it perform unacceptably in 19c

Comment: To diagnose performance problems, it requires more than just seeing the execution plan. You have to also see where it is making a cardinality mistake (expecting a certain number of rows but actually getting something far different) and where it is actually spending time. This requires some kind of wait interface polling, or using Active Session History and/or SQL Monitor data or reports, or using visualizing tools that use this data such as OEM and other 3rd party tools. Only once you identify where it is spending its time, you can make an informed decision about how to correct it.

Comment: And, as I suggested in my answer below, have you tried simply removing the parallel hint? Have you looked into what `package.get_code` is doing? Do you really need a PL/SQL call from SQL here? Is it something you can declare with `PRAGMA UDF`? Lots of things to check. As I said, a plan all by itself is neither good nor bad. It says nothing until you know more about the data and where time is actually being spent. There's no need to guess - Oracle instruments this and you can isolate the exact step where it is spending most of its time and pinpoint your tuning efforts there.

Comment: Actually we are split a big file(nearly 60 GB) into 8 chunk(small) files to avoid the time consume. so we written the pipe_row function(code updated for your reference) in 12c and it was work perfectly in12c. but when we migrate same code to 19c it won't work as expected mean it is create only one file though pipeline function instead of 8. after looking that we get the view did not work properly so then i started conversation here. we user prgama UDF and deterministic but nothing helps.

Comment: This new information changes entirely your question. There was nothing in your post before about reading or writing files. You need to tune the function call as a whole, not just the query you are passing to it. You will need to learn how to use ASH and/or SQL Monitor data to pinpoint where your performance issue is. It's nearly impossible to get good tuning advice from a forum like this, because so much depends on the nature of your data, the configuration of your database, and a lot of performance information from views we don't have access to, but you do, and it's too much to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query *is* using parallelism where it can, which is in the two full table scan of `T_...` You can see the `PX BLOCK ITERATOR` operation as the immediate parent of those table scans, and the `TQ` column shows PX team assignment.

But you are then aggregating the first one to a single row with `COUNT`. You then use the result in another query block but as it by definition will have only 1 row after that aggregation, PX is disabled for the rest of that execution branch. And for good reason - it serves no purpose when there's only one row to process. And there's nothing more for the row output to do but stream to the client, which has to be serial anyway.

Your next query block pulls from `dual`, which means again only 1 row. Nothing for parallelism to do here.

The next query block pulls from `T_....` again and uses parallelism for the scan.

The last block is again pulling 1 row from dual. Nothing for parallelism to do here.

I see no issue with how Oracle is employee parallelism here. It's doing it in the only place it can. The fact is, it is only doing that because you hinted it and requested parallelism. That's likely the wrong thing to do here. Since you aren't doing anything with the data downstream of these table scans (at least in the view itself), there's really no benefit to parallelism anywhere in this query. Your bottleneck will be fetching the results serially across the network to your client and consuming/displaying them there, not in anything the database is doing. Throwing parallelism at this will only result in idle but allocated PX slaves that other processes can't use. Further, even if you were doing joins and sorts and other operations that could benefit from the parallelism, your stats are saying that the only table in your query, `T_...` has only 13K rows. That's not enough to justify the startup time for parallel query. I would remove the hint and let this run serially.

It's quite normal for a change in database version to make sweeping changes to execution plans. Sometimes it helps, sometimes it hurts, sometimes you can't tell, but change of some kind can be expected with a major upgrade. That doesn't mean it's doing something wrong.

At the end of the day, what matters is not whether we understand or agree with what we see in the plan, but whether it actually performs acceptably. If it runs fast, no time should be spent on trying to figure out why Oracle made the decisions it made. Focus only on queries that run too slow to meet their needs, then dig into the plan to understand what mistake it is making (if any) given your knowledge of the data. In this case, parallelism isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

The parallel hint is working. You still have "PX Send" => "PX Coordinator" in 2nd exec plan, just little bit lower.

I do not what is inside that view, but for some reason Oracle decided to process part of SQL in parallel and then to apply SORT => UNION ALL sequentially on a result produced by parallel worker processes.

Comment: view and full explain plan has been updated. there is no change in view but it was working perfectly in 12c not working in 19c.